# API endpoint link is working in Postman but not in Ruby on Rails with ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, postman, activeresource

I am working on Ruby on Rails application which requires to access an External API via GET requests. The request needs to send some parameters with request. I have used Activeresource gem for accessing API. The API request is working fine in Postman and giving expected records but gives me a 400 error from Rails application.

Following is the code

```
class PayRunEmploymentHeroBase < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://api.yourpayroll.com.au"
  self.user = ENV['EMPLOYMENT_HERO_USERNAME']
  self.element_name = ""
  self.include_format_in_path = false
  self.prefix = "/api/v2/business/:business_id/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised gt datetime':finalised_date'"
end
```

I am pasting here the details of 400 error while accessing the link from Rails app.

```
Reloading...
 => true
2.3.0 :006 > PayRunEmploymentHeroBase.find(:all, params: {:business_id => business_id, :finalised_date =>  finalised_date})
##############################################INFO##############################################
{
  "method": "get",
  "request_uri": "https://api.yourpayroll.com.au:443/api/v2/business/48058/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised gt datetime'2017-11-16'",
  "http_status": "400",
  "http_message": "Bad Request"
}
##############################################INFO##############################################
ActiveResource::BadRequest: Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request.
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:141:in `handle_response'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:126:in `request'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:85:in `block in get'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:220:in `with_auth'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:85:in `get'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1073:in `find_every'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeresource-5.1.0/lib/active_resource/base.rb:974:in `find'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.0.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.0.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/bebble1/work/awe/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.0.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `load'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.0.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `load'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/bebble1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

I have also attached a picture here of the outcome from Rails app

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the request headers and body (if exist) in your postman?

Comment: HI, @KSDPutra I have updated the request with an image which shows headers in Postman too. I am not facing authorization issues at the moment as I have other requests which are working fine. What I think is that issue is with filter parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not authenticating with Rails app. And I am sure you have set authentication username/password in Postman.

Set `self.password = "password"` (use your own password) to `PayRunEmploymentHeroBase` and it will work.

**Update**:
It's actually your url is not encoded, do this and it will solve the issue:

`self.prefix = "/api/v2/business/:business_id/payrun?$filter=" + URI::encode("DateFinalised gt datetime':finalised_date'")`

Comment: Hi Kien, I don't have any authorization issues since I am able to get the results for other API links. 

Since I have provided the API key within the username so we don't need username and password.

Comment: Hi @cvibha, sorry that it didn't work. I saw your screenshot, hopefully the api key is not real, or else you need to censor it.

Maybe the issue is the filter, could you try to encode it?

`self.prefix = URI.encode_www_form_component("/api/v2/business/:business_id/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised gt datetime':finalised_date'")`
 and see if it works

Comment: The API key is real Kien since I am able to get other API requests working fine. I tried with encoding you providing but it's not working either. I am receiving the following URL after the encoding the request. 
"https://api.yourpayroll.com.au:443%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fbusiness%2F%3Abusiness_id%2Fpayrun%3F%24filter%3DDateFinalised+gt+datetime%27%3Afinalised_date%27?business_id=48058&finalised_date=2017-11-16"

Comment: Sorry about that, encoding the whole part is not good. I tested with only encoding the filter params and it didn't give me 400: `self.prefix = "/api/v2/business/:business_id/payrun?$filter=" + URI.encode_www_form_component("DateFinalised gt datetime':finalised_date'")`. That makes the final url is `https://api.yourpayroll.com.au:443/api/v2/business/48058/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised+gt+datetime%272017-11-16%27`. Please try and let me know

Comment: The request URI generated after doing that is as follows:

  "request_uri": "https://api.yourpayroll.com.au:443/api/v2/business/48058/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised+gt+datetime%27%3Afinalised_date%27?finalised_date=2019-10-27T00%3A00%3A00",

It is now giving me 500 error

Comment: @cvibha 500 means server got exception and could not handle the request, better than 400 (client's fault).

I think the encode method I recommended is not working. Please try `URI::encode` : like this: `self.prefix = "/api/v2/business/:business_id/payrun?$filter=" + URI::encode("DateFinalised gt datetime':finalised_date'")` and that makes https://api.yourpayroll.com.au:443/api/v2/business/48058/payrun?$filter=DateFinalised%20gt%20datetime'2017-11-16'. Please give it a try

Comment: Cool. I'll update my answer and please accept it :).